# 14.04LTS Microphone Buzzing noise bad

Tags: 14.04, microphone

My Microphone started acting up badly this morning has a loud buzz, it has got to be software it was working fine last night installed updates and shutdown last night and boom here we are, oh and i have a Microphone jack microphone and a internal mic, both are acting up... Please help

PLEASE help i need to use skype.

Dafull97

Comment: Please some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Run alsamixer in a terminal and try to mute unused input (digital ...) , disable "loopback" switch .   You may have to press F6 to select main soundcard.
Look [alsamixer how to](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer)

Comment: Loopback switch?

Comment: I tried it it didn't work :(